# Bitcoin-QT Windows Safety Concerns

Tags: bitcoin-core

According to https://www.file.net/process/bitcoin-qt.exe.html

"The application uses ports to connect to or from a LAN or the Internet. Bitcoin-qt.exe is able to connect to the Internet, record keyboard and mouse inputs and monitor applications. Therefore the technical security rating is 31% dangerous."

It is my understanding that when port 8333 is enabled the node shares its blockchain data with other nodes through the network, however this is not a requirement to run Bitcoin Core and is not enabled by default. Is there any other ports used or possible vulnerabilities when a node is not configured to transmit outbound information through port 8333?

Also curious if anyone can elaborate on these safety concerns particularly relating to "record[ing] keyboard and mouse inputs and monitor[ing] applications"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is my understanding that when port 8333 is enabled the node shares its blockchain data with other nodes through the network, however this is not a requirement to run Bitcoin Core and is not enabled by default.

Your understanding is incorrect. Bitcoin Core is an application that requires network access to work. Outbound connections are always possible and do not require port 8333 to be open or available. Port 8333 is only required to be available and open to the internet if you want to receive incoming connections. Listening on port 8333 is on by default, but you typically need to configure your firewall(s) to allow incoming connections to port 8333.

> Also curious if anyone can elaborate on these safety concerns particularly relating to "record[ing] keyboard and mouse inputs and monitor[ing] applications"?

Bitcoin Core has keyboard and mouse input in order for people to actually be able to use it, therefore it has to be able to "record keyboard and mouse inputs".

I don't know what they mean by "monitor applications". That's a pretty vague description and could mean a lot of things.